# Does MySQL scale on a single multi-processor machine?

Tags: mysql

My application's typical DB usage is to read/update on one large table. I wonder if MySQL scales read operations on a single multi-processor machine? How about write operations - are they able to utilize multi-processors?

By the way - unfortunately I am not able to optimize the table schema.

Thank you.

Setup details:

- X64, quard core
- Single hard disk (no RAID)
- Plenty of memory (4GB+)
- Linux 2.6
- MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using conventional hard disks, you'll often find you run out of IO bandwidth before you run out of CPU cores. The only way to pin a four core machine is to have a very high performance SSD striped RAID array.

If you're not able to optimize the schema you have very limited options. This is like asking to tune a car without lifting the hood. Maybe you can change the tires or use better gasoline, but fundamental performance gains come from several factors, including, most notably, additional indexes and strategically de-normalizing data.

In database land, 4GB of memory is almost nothing, 8GB is the absolute minimum for a system with any loading, and a single disk is **a very bad idea**. At the very least you should have some form of mirroring for data integrity reasons.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I indeed with that my client will allow me to change the table schema haha... the advise on disk setup sounds very useful!

Comment: Even a consumer SSD like the Intel 520 series provides an **order of magnitude** increase in database performance. It's absolutely crazy to expect a single conventional hard-drive to hold up under load.